# My program should calculate prime numbers, but stops after the first number

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, boolean, primes

So I wrote this little program that is supposed to check if a number is a prime number and if it's the case should add it to an arraylist. The problem is that it just adds the number 3 and then stops. Could somebody please explain me why it behaves like that?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList Primzahlen=new ArrayList();
        int current=1;
        boolean prim=true;
        for(int a=0;a<100;a++){
            for(int b=2;b<current;b++){
                if(current%b==0){
                    prim=false;
                }
                if(b==current-1){
                    if(prim==true){
                        Primzahlen.add(current);
                    }
                }
            }
            current++;
        }
        System.out.println(Primzahlen);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try stepping through your code in a debugger.

Comment: You set `prim=false` if `current%b==0` but you never set it to true again.

Comment: Thanks. I think that I shouldn't have missed such an obvious mistake.

Comment: it's normal to make "dumb" mistakes. But you need to learn how to identify them by debugging. You can't be forever dependent on others to find your mistakes for you.

Comment: Move `boolean prim=true;` before the inner loop.

Comment: Why `if(prim==true)` instead of just `if (prim)`?

Comment: Please follow the Java coding conventions, particularly with respect to names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset prim to true after you are over with checking the current value .

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList Primzahlen=new ArrayList();
        int current=1;
        boolean prim=true;
        Primzahlen.add(2);
        for(int a=3;a<100;a++){
            for(int b=2;b<current;b++){
                if(current%b==0){
                    prim=false;
                }
                if(b==current-1){
                    if(prim==true){
                        Primzahlen.add(current);
                    }
                }
            }
            prim=true;
            current++;
        }
        System.out.println(Primzahlen);
    }
```

Notice the prim=true near current++

Comment: Or just move `boolean prim=true;` down one line, as @saka1029 suggested in the comments.

Comment: Many ways to solve a problem. I posted it before seeing the comment.